# Multiply weights after using dropout in training - PyTorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, dropout

I have a Pytorch regression model as follows:

```py
    model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(n_in, n_h_1),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Dropout(p=0.1),
                      nn.Linear(n_h_1, n_h_2),
                      nn.ReLU(),
                      nn.Linear(n_h_2, n_out))
```

As you can see, I have used a Dropout regularization layer with dropout probability of 0.1. 
When the training is completed, we should disable the dropout. This can be achieved using `model.eval()`. Reference to  [this StackOverflow answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/44293/how-dropout-work-during-testing-in-neural-network) and other resources, we should multiply the output of hidden layer with  `(1-p)` during inferencing of model.

My question is: do we have to do this manually using pytorch or the library handles this itself  after applying `model.eval()`?
If we have to do it ourselves, how can we achieve thisfor the given model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch handles this with scaling the output of the dropout layer at training time with this probability:

[image]

So it handles this itself after applying `model.eval()`. You can lookup their code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/dropout.py):